# R remove category values whose count is less than 10% of over al data and find the average of the other columns associated with that category

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have dataset of the following format

```
Cat     v1  V2
Low     10  1
Low     10  2
Low     10  3
Low     10  1
Low     10  2
Low     10  3
Low     10  1
Low     10  2
Low     10  3
Low     10  1
Low     10  2
Low     10  3
Low     10  1
Low     10  2
Low     10  3
Low     10  1
High    90  8
High    90  9
High    90  19
VeryLow 1   23
```

What i am trying to do is that if the frequency any of  the category is less than 10%of the total rows in the dataset i will ignore that category and find the average of the two columns(for each category remaining ,like a groupby) in the data set.

So my final data set will look like is

```
Cat   Avgv1 Avgv2
Low    10   1.9
High   90   1.2
```

> Very Low was removed as it was less than .1 * nrow(mydataset)

Is there some way to do this in R.I am very hopeful!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be:

```
#split the df according to your categories
categs <- split(df, df$Cat)

#then use lapply on the splits
#if a category has less than .1 * the rows of the original data.frame return NULL
#else calculate the averages.
#Using do.call(rbind... will remove the NULLs
do.call(rbind,
lapply(categs, function(x){
  if(nrow(x) < 0.1*nrow(df)) return(NULL) else aggregate(cbind(v1,V2)~Cat, x, FUN=mean)
}))
```

Output:

```
      Cat v1      V2
High High 90 12.0000
Low   Low 10  1.9375
```

Comment: simple ,elegant and curvy!liked it!!

Comment: Thanks, happy I could be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

An approach with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

low_cat_freqs <- df %>%
  group_by(Cat) %>%
  tally() %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
  filter(freq <= 0.10)

low_cat_freqs
# Source: local data frame [1 x 3]
# 
#       Cat     n  freq
#    (fctr) (int) (dbl)
# 1 VeryLow     1  0.05

df %>%
  filter(!Cat %in% low_cat_freqs$Cat) %>%
  # continue to do as what you wish....
  group_by(Cat) %>%
  summarise(avg_v1 = mean(v1),
            avg_v2 = mean(V2))

#      Cat avg_v1  avg_v2
#   (fctr)  (dbl)   (dbl)
# 1   High     90 12.0000
# 2    Low     10  1.9375
```

Comment: Thanks but i wanted the average for v1 and average for v2.Aren't we missing the average for v1 here?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `data.table` as

```
library('data.table')
DT <- data.table(my.data.set)

DT <- DT[,
         .N,
         by = 'Cat'
         ][,
           freq:= N/sum(N)
           ][freq > my.number,][,
                               avg := N/sum(N)
                               ]
```